# Unable to include JSON Schema validation json file in build.gradle during runtime

Tags: gradle, hyperledger-fabric, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to make http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema# to be in local repository.
But it is unable to find the referred JSON in any of the path, be it root, resources or current directly or inside the jar.

As these are run-time exception, it seems the json-schema.org/draft-04/schema.json file in resource as well with the jar is not in the pakaged build.

Is there a way, I can define in JavaCompile in build.gradle to pick the json files

Below are the code snippet

Schema.json:

```
   {
    "$ref": "file://json-schema-draft-04-schema.json",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Hyperledger Fabric Contract Definition JSON Schema",
    "required": [
        "info",
        "contracts"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "info": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/info"
        },
        "contracts": {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^.*$": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/contract"
                }
            }
        },
        "components": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/components"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "info": {
            "type": "object",
            "description": "General information about the API.",
            "required": [
                "version",
                "title"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "A unique and precise title of the API."
                },
                "version": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "A semantic version number of the API."
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "A longer description of the API. Should be different from the title.  GitHub Flavored Markdown is allowed."
                },
                "termsOfService": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The terms of service for the API."
                },
                "contact": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/contact"
                },
                "license": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/license"
                }
            }
        },
```

Referred to json json-schema-draft-04-schema.json:

```
   {
    "id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "Core schema meta-schema",
    "definitions": {
        "schemaArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": { "$ref": "#" }
        },
        "positiveInteger": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        },
        "positiveIntegerDefault0": {
            "allOf": [ { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveInteger" }, { "default": 0 } ]
        },
        "simpleTypes": {
            "enum": [ "array", "boolean", "integer", "null", "number", "object", "string" ]
        },
        "stringArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "type": "string" },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "$schema": {
```

Error Quote

```
   0|Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /json-schema-draft-04-schema.json (No such file or directory)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.internal.DefaultSchemaClient.get(DefaultSchemaClient.java:20)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonPointerEvaluator.executeWith(JsonPointerEvaluator.java:78)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonPointerEvaluator.lambda$forURL$1(JsonPointerEvaluator.java:121)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonPointerEvaluator.query(JsonPointerEvaluator.java:151)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.ReferenceLookup.lookup(ReferenceLookup.java:173)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.ReferenceSchemaExtractor.extract(SchemaExtractor.java:193)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.AbstractSchemaExtractor.extract(SchemaExtractor.java:113)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.runSchemaExtractors(SchemaLoader.java:383)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.loadSchemaObject(SchemaLoader.java:360)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonValue$Multiplexer.requireAny(JsonValue.java:46)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.load(SchemaLoader.java:434)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder.validate(MetadataBuilder.java:87)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder.initialize(MetadataBuilder.java:115)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter.main(ContractRouter.java:134)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /json-schema-draft-04-schema.json (No such file or directory)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:739)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:1059)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     at org.everit.json.schema.loader.internal.DefaultSchemaClient.get(DefaultSchemaClient.java:18)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|     ... 13 more
```

build.gradle

```
   plugins {

    id 'java'
    //id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.3'

}

version '0.0.1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {

    // flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }


}

dependencies {
    //compile group: 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java', name: 'fabric-chaincode-shim',version: '1.4.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') // local fabric-chaincode-shim which has json
    // schema locally store in the jar. Also, there is one in resources folder.
    compile group: 'org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java', name: 'fabric-sdk-java', version: '1.4.4'
    compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11'
    implementation 'com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema:1.11.1'
    compile 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'chaincode'
    version = null
    classifier = null

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-parameters"
}
```

Both the file are inside an executable jar.
I tried putting the reference .json file in root of the project as well, but no luck.
Tried using classpath:// as well. 
No luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues here.

First, you are assuming the library you are using supports the `file://` protocol. Is it specifically documented that you can references local files this way in the library you are using? JSON Schema itself makes no assumptions about protocol support, and does not know about itself as a file in a folder structure.

Second, you cannot use `$ref` alongside other keywords in the same object. Even if your reference did resolve, it would make all the other keywords in the schema ignored. You need to wrap it using an `allOf`.

Comment: Thanks, It seems (I am assuming) because these json files are locally stored, it is not getting packaged properly. Hence, it is missing in the output. Adding gradle.build also.
Perhaps it is gradle.build configuration issue.